# Get expired value with Jedis

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I followed this guide [Redis Key expire notification with Jedis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26406598/1896897) to listen expired key. But i don't know how to get its expired value.

Is there a way to get value of the expired key ?

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. All keyspace notifications, expiry events included, do not provide the values of the keys.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think of using hashmap to keep the values of the keys. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: In Spring Data Redis we write a phantom value (actual a copy) with a longer timeout and listen to expiry keyspace events (need to be activated, see http://redis.io/topics/notifications#configuration). As soon the original key expires we get notified and read the phantom object so we have access to the copy of the value.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details - most importantly why you need the expired values.

Comment: Kudos to @christoph-strobl, that was his idea.