# Detect client connection drop using Jersey/Java

Tags: java, ios, api, jersey

I have created Restful Web Services using Jersey over Java. My client is an iOS app which sends user data after every 1 minute. What would be the best way to detect that client has stopped sending the data due to either network lost or app killed by the user. I want to detect it on my API server.

Comment: How about having a timestamp for the last request received for all connected clients in a list and have a thread run through the list and identify those older than 2 minutes?

Comment: I am thinking on similar lines. Trying to use Redis to cache the keys with expire time,refreshing the keys on each call and creating a callback on expiry

Comment: I am able to do it using Redis notification callback mechanism. For reference I used
1. http://basrikahveci.com/a-simple-jedis-publish-subscribe-example/
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406303/redis-key-expire-notification-with-jedis

Comment: Good to hear that. You could answer your own question and accept it. It could help someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do it using Redis event notification mechanism. For reference I used

- basrikahveci.com/a-simple-jedis-publish-subscribe-example
- [Redis Key expire notification with Jedis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406303/redis-key-expire-notification-with-jedis)