# Redis Key expire notification with Jedis not working

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am using Jedis 2.9.0 version and i followed

[Redis Key expire notification with Jedis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406303/redis-key-expire-notification-with-jedis#)

but onPMessage method in Listener is not called when redis key expires.

in Subscriber I used

```
    jedis.psubscribe(new KeyExpiredListener(), "*");
```

When I am running server

```
    jedis.set("notify", "test");
    jedis.expire("notify", 10);
```

but After 10 seconds Redis key expired but  onPMessage did not trigger.

Comment: have you tried to replace `*` with the specific keyspace channel? Like `"__key*__:*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expire keyspace notification isn't fired just when a key has expired but (taken from [the docs](https://redis.io/topics/notifications)):

> - When the key is accessed by a command and is found to be expired.
> - Via a background system that looks for expired keys in background, incrementally, in order to be able to also collect keys that are never
>     accessed.

In addition, maybe you've not enabled keyspace notifications:

> By default keyspace events notifications are disabled because while
>   not very sensible the feature uses some CPU power. Notifications are
>   enabled using the notify-keyspace-events of redis.conf or via the
>   CONFIG SET.

Some [docs page](https://redis.io/topics/notifications) will explain you how to enable them.

Comment: Thanks Matías Fidemraizer. I just added $AKE for notify-keyspace-events and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @GouravSoni You're welcome! I'm glad you could solve your problem! :)