# redis pub sub only for a certain set of keys?

Tags: redis

I have a use case in which I want to enable notification only for a certain set of keys, so that when those keys expire I can get a notification from redis.

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406303/redis-key-expire-notification-with-jedis) answer to implement this.

I have set parameter notify-keyspace-events to "Ex"

To accomplish this I am adding keys that I want notification for in DB-0 and the other keys in DB-1. But I am recieveing notification for both the DBs. Is there any way to just get notification from a particular DB?

According to redis  documentation :

"*Redis can notify Pub/Sub clients about events happening in the key space.
This feature is documented at http://redis.io/topics/notifications
For instance if keyspace events notification is enabled, and a client
performs a DEL operation on key "foo" stored in the **Database 0**, two
messages will be published via Pub/Sub:*

PUBLISH **keyspace@0**:foo del

PUBLISH **keyevent@0**:del foo
"

But I am receiving notification from both DB-0 and DB-1.

PS : I know I can filter keys in my application, but I store too many expiring keys in redis and sending notification for all the expiring will increase load on my redis server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you subscribed to a pattern that matches all DBs' notification message, e.g. `PSUBSCRIBE __key*__:*`.

In fact, you can specify the db index in the subscribed pattern: `PSUBSCRIBE __keyspace@0__:*` and `PSUBSCRIBE __keyevent@0__:*`. This way, you'll only received notification of `DB0`.